# how to insert callback function in OnInit function?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a gridview column that contains clickable row. when the row is clicked then the pop up gridview will appear. For example : when i click on the row, the pop up gridview will appear according to ID. ** row cat ID - pop up gridview for cat ID **

My code works for displaying pop up gridview for all ID but when i insert the clientsideevent click in asp.net as below then the Pop up gridview doesnt pop up and when i insert callback function in ASPxHyperlink_Init like this

`link.ClientSideEvents.Click = String.Format("function(s, e) {{ OnMoreInfoClick('{0}');UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(""" & Eval("LotID").ToString & """); }}", sno)`

then this error showed

`System.InvalidOperationException: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.`

My code are as below :

ASP.NET Mark Up

```
   function OnMoreInfoClick(contentUrl) {

                popupControl.Show();

            }

   <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  VisibleIndex="8" Caption="Detail" EditFormSettings-Visible="False" >
                                     <DataItemTemplate>
                                        <dx:ASPxHyperLink ID="ASPxHyperLink" runat="server" OnInit="ASPxHyperLink_Init" >
                                            <ClientSideEvents Click= '<%# "function(s,e) { UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(""" & Eval("LotID").ToString & """); }" %>'></ClientSideEvents>
                                        </dx:ASPxHyperLink>
                                     </DataItemTemplate>
                                    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

VB.NET

```
    Protected Sub ASPxHyperLink_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim link As ASPxHyperLink = CType(sender, ASPxHyperLink)

        Dim templateContainer As GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer = CType(link.NamingContainer, GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer)

        Dim rowVisibleIndex As Integer = templateContainer.VisibleIndex
        Dim sno As String = templateContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(rowVisibleIndex, "sno").ToString()
        Dim SplitTable As String = templateContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(rowVisibleIndex, "Detail").ToString()
        ' Dim contentUrl As String = String.Format("{0}?sno={1}", sno)

        link.Text = "Split Table"

        link.NavigateUrl = "javascript:void(0);"

        link.ClientSideEvents.Click = String.Format("function(s, e) {{ OnMoreInfoClick('{0}');}}", sno)

    End Sub



   Protected Sub UpdateSplitGrid_CustomCallback(sender As Object, e As ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs)

        Dim mssql_string As String = "Data Source=xx;Initial Catalog=xx;User Id=xx;Password=xx;Provider=SQLNCLI10"
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(mssql_string)
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable
        Dim xdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

        con.Open()

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from PTHOME.dbo.SplitTable where LotID = '" + e.Parameters + "'", con)

        xdapter.SelectCommand = cmd

        xdapter.Fill(dt1)

        con.Close()

        UpdateSplitGrid.DataSource = dt1
        UpdateSplitGrid.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Please guide me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you cannot use `Eval()` in `UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(""" & Eval("LotID").ToString & """)`. Try using `UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(s.GetFocusedRowIndex())` to perform callback from certain selected row (and still not understand what you're trying to achieve, can you explain it in simple words?).

Comment: erm, i just want to click on the row then pop up gridview displays all the data related to the row ID.

Comment: By which way you're triggering "details" popup (assumed using `ASPxPopupControl`) to show after row click (or button click) event? Also you may need to pass the value from client-side events to detail grid.

Comment: the ASPxHyperLink_Init function's OnmoreInfoClick there to trigger the pop up and the javascript OnMoreInfoClick(contentUrl) {
                popupControl.Show();   
            } and by row click.

Comment: how can i put this function(s,e) { UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(""" & Eval("LotID").ToString & """);} in javascript or Init? the value

Answer (score 0):

This line of code throws `InvalidOperationException` because `Click` client-side event doesn't support data binding, neither with `Bind()` nor `Eval()`:

```
<ClientSideEvents Click= '<%# "function(s,e) { UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(""" & Eval("LotID").ToString & """); }" %>'></ClientSideEvents>
```

However, as far as I know, you can create a method which takes the hyperlink as `GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer` and put the index there:

```
Protected Function GetRowIndex(ByVal link As DevExpress.Web.ASPxHyperLink) As Integer
    Return (TryCast(link.NamingContainer, DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer)).VisibleIndex
End Function
```

Then you can use it in `Click` event for client-side like example below:

```
<ClientSideEvents Click='<%# "function(s,e) { UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(""" & GetRowIndex(Container).ToString & """); }" %>'>
</ClientSideEvents>
```

**Additional note:**

Inside `CustomCallback` event handler, if you want to get certain row value based from its column name, use this line below:

```
Dim row As Object = UpdateSplitGrid.GetRowValues(Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters), "LotID");
```

Then, you can do something with provided value (note that use `SqlParameter` instead of string concatenation to insert query values).

Similar issue (using `ASPxMenu` instead of `ASPxHyperLink`):

[ASPxGridView - How to pass a parameter to the PerformCallback method from the markup expression](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q255705/get-row-visible-index-when-template-control-clicked-client-side)

Comment: thanks, but i have changed the Onit function to normal javascript pop out and it works.  ClientSideEvents-Click='<%# "function(s,e) { UpdateSplitGrid.PerformCallback(""" & Eval("LotID").ToString & """); OnMoreInfoClick();}" %>'